# Install4j: adding a service icon to System tray

Tags: java, service, icons, installation, install4j

I created an installer through the install4j software. The installer creates & adds a service which runs in the background.

I am trying to figure if it is possible to add a System Tray icon (right bottom corner of the screen) to show that my service is running. I managed to get it working by using the following code in my main class:

```
            final Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("funny-icon.png"));
            final TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(image, "Device Agent");

            if(SystemTray.isSupported())
            {
                final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
                icon.setImageAutoSize(true);

                try
                {
                    tray.add(icon);
                    ...
```

The code above works only when I execute it through the IDE, not from the `.exe` created by the installer.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do so, because a service cannot access the UI. Previous Windows versions had the concept of an "interactive service" but this has been removed since Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That explains everything.